# How can I programmatically access the cron schedules for my Airflow DAGs?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to build a custom UI built around the executions of airflow tasks. One piece of information I need is the cron schedule of each DAG.

I cannot find this in any of the tables used by the Airflow scheduler. Am I missing something obvious?

Without writing a crawler to parse DAG python files themselves, where can I find the cron schedules for my DAGs (by database connection, api call, or anything else that I can programmatically access)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instantiate a `airflow.models.DagBag` object, all the `DAG` objects, and their `schedule_interval` (which has their scheduling information), is available from the `dags` dictionary attribute on the `DagBag` object.

```
from airflow import models
dag_bag = models.DagBag()
for dag in dag_bag.dags.values():
    print(dag.schedule_interval)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much.

Comment: @StephenBourget Please upvote if this answer worked for you.

Comment: @andscoop. I marked it as a correct answer. New members can't upvote.